# Complex gradient animation

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to replicate the complex gradient animation I saw in Walli mobile application. I tried with CSS but no success. It would be great if someone helped me figuring out how the animated background of this button was made.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xiGA.gif

Comment: So what have you [tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: To animate gradient, you should animate gradient-positon...

Comment: [CSS radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient#Non-centered_gradient) could do the trick. Animate the x-offset.

Comment: So far I tried "background-position" but didn't get the same effect